# Seleccionar archivo Random, no una carpeta

Tags: python

Mi problema es que quiero seleccionar una archivo random en Python y no una carpeta, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
import random
file = "/home/file"
random = random.choice(os.listdir(file))
print(random)
```

Dentro de "file" hay archivos y carpetas, y yo solo quiero llamar a los archivos, no a las carpetas, como comente antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues para empezar `listdir()` lista los archivos y carpetas dentro del directorio deseado... 
Y eso está bien !!! Lo que debes hacer luego de listarlos, es filtrarlos.

Python tiene la función `isfile()` para esto.

```
import os
path = "/path/";
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)):
        print(file)
```

Luego para seleccionar un random. Podrías guardar el archivo dentro de un array, y seleccionar un random de ese array.

(Creo que es así, compruebalo por favor, no tengo como acá XD)

Comment: Lo que hice fue sacar las carpetas, pero, mil gracias por tu ayuda, ya lo se para la proxima vez. Pero, seguro de que si funciona.

Comment: XD igual prueba a agregar el filtro, ya que es lo unico que te faltaba.